# How can I open ~/.android/adb_usb.ini for the Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, macos, debugging, kindle-fire

This is a pretty basic question, but I can't figure out how to get to the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file in order to edit it so I can develop on my Fire. What does the ~ mean? Where is .android? Just a little confused...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~` is a shortcut for the home directory that usually has your name on it, the longer variant is usually `/Users/yourusername`. `.android` is therefore found under `/Users/yourusername/.android`. Note that files and folder which begin with a dot are considered hidden. This means you have to show them on some way *(just [googled that](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) out of curiosity, seems like you have to do some command line magic)*.

Alternatively you can use `Go -> Go to folder` in the finder from the menu and just type `~/.android` into the field that pops up. Click ok and you're in the folder.