# I can't find adb_usb.ini file in .android folder?

Tags: android

i have to add a device for debugging. we can do that by adding a hex value in adb_usb.ini file. But i am not able to locate adb_usb.ini file.

Anyone is having idea, why it is not there in .andorid folder.

Comment: What platform are you on? there is no .ini configuration file in Linux.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369341/how-can-i-open-android-adb-usb-ini-for-the-kindle-fire?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: hi, i am using windows 7. i am having access to .android folder. i assume adb_usb.ini should be there. .android folder is not hidden as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the adb_usb.ini file is not present in the .android folder, we can create it.  It should contain device vendor hex values, one per line.

Steps for Windows 7/8:

1. Go to `C:\Users\<user name>\.android`
2. Create a file.
3. Rename to adb_usb.ini
4. Paste the following lines:

   ```
   # add your vendor IDs, one per line
   0x1949
   0x18D1
   ```

Comment: What is the benefit of this ".android" folder ? There's cache folder inside it, can I delete it ?

Comment: Im not understanding what a vendor ID is or where that page mentions it @Otiel

Comment: @MarkDodsons The page seems to have changed, the vendor IDs are not listed anymore.