# After adb reboot - adb devices does not show up

Tags: android, adb

Unless, I physically unplug and plug the usb again into the computer, adb devices does NOT show up. I have done almost every possible thing I could think of. I have usb debug option turned on under developer options, I tried:
 1. [i cann't find adb_usb.ini file in .android folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830407/i-cannt-find-adb-usb-ini-file-in-android-folder)
 2. [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)
 3. http://turbulentsky.com/device-not-found-error-from-adb-on-mac-os-x.html
 I can go on and on.. I am seeing this on Nexus 5,7. Samsung S3, S5, S6, Galaxy Tab A, Alcatel one touch (just to name a few). Any advice would be great

Answer (score 1):

Kill the ADB from your Android Terminal, if there was the same issues u can do second thing Restart your PC if that is not also usefull, do third thing go to SDK manager and there uninstall the Platform-tools and restart your android and install it again ....